# how do you separate first middle and last name in php

Tags: php

i am having trouble separating first middle and last name using strpos.

```
// capitalize the first letters only
    $fullName = strtolower($fullName);
    $fullName = ucwords($fullName);

    // get first name from complete name
    $spacePos = strpos($fullName,' ');
    $forename = substr($fullName,0,$spacePos);

    // middle name
    $middlenameLength = strlen($fullName);
    $surnamelength = $length-$spacePos;
    $middle = strpos($fullName," ", $spacePos + 1);

    // last name
    $length = strlen($fullName);
    $surnameLength = $length-$spacePos;
    $surname = substr($fullName, $spacePos+1, $surnameLength);
```

Comment: Use `explode()` to split the name into an array.

Comment: Why don't you just use 2 different inputs and concatenate if needed?

Comment: There goes your edit @Barmar

Comment: Yeah, it's best to use separate inputs, that's how everyone does it if they need to break up the name.

Comment: Yeah, but too many possible answers and I fear they're probably not looking to break up what they already started @Barmar - So I voted as too broad.

Comment: Call `explode()` to split the name at spaces. The first element of the array is the first name, the last element is the last name, and if the array length is more than 2, concatenate all the middle elements with `implode()` to get the middle names.

Comment: Trying to split the data from one field into first and last names will always be an exercise in pain. Just use the name as a whole and forget the notion of first, last, and middle. E.g., what if you have `John Smith Jr.` or `Mr. John Smith` or `Sir John Franklin William Smith III`.

Answer (score 1):

Split the name up using `explode()`. The first name is the first element of the array, the last name is the last element of the array, and the middle name is the concatenation of the middle elements.

```
$names = explode(' ', $fullName);
$firstName = '';
$lastName = $names[count($names)-1];
$middleName = '';
if (count($names) > 1) {
    $firstName = $names[0];
    if (count($names) > 2) {
        $middleName = implode(' ', array_slice($names, 1, count($names)-2));
    }
}
```

This won't work if you have honorifics or suffixes like "Jr.". This is why most web forms have separate fields for all these things. Reliable name parsing requires natural language processing.

Comment: Nice answer. Side note though: `[]` [array maps](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) are for PHP > 5.4 should their version be 5.4 or lower.

Comment: Where did I write any array literals using `[]`?

Comment: `$names[count($names)-1]` < right there.

Comment: That's an array index, not an array literal.

Comment: So that works even in 5.4? I didn't know that. So I guess I missed something then.

Comment: Array subscripts have worked forever. What is the older syntax you're thinking I should be using?

Comment: I think you're confusing this with `someFunc()[$subscript]`, which is new in 5.4.

Comment: Probably. I guess there's something about `[]` arrays that I didn't grasp for older versions of PHP such as 5.4 and lower.

Comment: There's two things new in 5.4: array literals like `$array = [1, 2, 3];` and subscripting function calls `func()[1]`

Comment: But `$array[1]` has been the syntax forever, there's nothing new about that.

Comment: Ok thanks Barmar. Yeah, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

When a double space is used, and you are using explode, you will get empty list items.

```
$fullName = 'Jack Max  Smith';
$names = explode(' ', $fullName);
```

> [0] => 'Jack', [1] => 'Max', [2] => ' ', [3] => 'Smith'

---

A better way is to use a regex to split the names into separate parts.

```
$fullName = 'Jack Max  Smith';
$names = preg_split('/\s+/', $fullName);
```

> [0] => 'Jack', [1] => 'Max', [2] => 'Smith'

---

To get the names seperated in custom variables you could do

```
$fullName = 'Jack Max  Smith';
$names = preg_split('/\s+/', $fullName);

$first = $middle = $last = '';
switch(count($names)) {
  case 3: list($first, $middle, $last) = $names; break;
  case 2: list($first, $last) = $names; break;
  case 1: list($last) = $names; break;
}
```